# Summarizing a jQuery code

Tags: jquery, code-cleanup

This code is not clean. But it works

I need a code clean. Is there a way to convert this code into a clean code there?

```
var favIcon = $(obj).find('i').first();
                if (favIcon.hasClass('fa-star')) {
                    favIcon.removeClass('fa-star');
                    favIcon.addClass('fa-star-o');
                } else {
                    favIcon.removeClass('fa-star-o');
                    favIcon.addClass('fa-star');
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `toggleClass()` and do it all in one line

```
$(obj).find('i').first().toggleClass('fa-star fa-star-o');
```

**[toggleClass() docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**